# Find out what page is the user looking at

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

How can I determine if the user is looking at a particular page in a flexdashboard? I have a global sidebar panel of filters that applies to all pages except one of the filters in the sidebar doesn't apply to one of the pages. In this example, let's say I don't want the `selectInput()` to be displayed on Page 3.

````
---
title: "Which Page?"
runtime: shiny
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=400}
=====================================
```{r}
textInput("text", NULL)

selectInput("select", NULL, LETTERS[1:5])
```

Page 1
=====================================

Page 2
=====================================

Page 3
=====================================
````

I was hoping to use `session$clientData$url_hash` but this is static and based on the page the user initially opened. You can put this in the sidebar section to see how it (doesn't) change. Other ideas I've found are to use `window.location` or `is.visible` in js but not sure how to integrate.

```r
print_info <- function(x) {
  allvalues <- 
    lapply(
      X = sort(names(x)), 
      FUN = function(name) {
        item <- x[[name]]
        paste(name, item, sep = " = ")
      }
    )
  
  paste(allvalues, collapse = "\n")
}
    
output$client_data <- renderText(print_info(session$clientData))
verbatimTextOutput("client_data")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 : "pure Shiny"

You can take advantage of the fact that `renderXXX()` is only calculated on active page. For example here we can use `renderUI()` on each page to update a reactive value `tab` with the current page number. That value is then used in the side bar to check if the `selectInput` will be displayed with the `renderUI` :

````
---
title: "Which Page?"
runtime: shiny
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=400}
=====================================
```{r}
textInput("text", NULL)

tab <- reactiveVal(1)
renderUI({
  if(tab()!=3)
    selectInput("select", NULL, LETTERS[1:5])
})
```

Page 1
=====================================
```{r}
renderUI({tab();tab(1);NULL})
```

Page 2
=====================================
```{r}
renderUI({tab();tab(2);NULL})
```

Page 3
=====================================
```{r}
renderUI({tab();tab(3);NULL})
```
````

## Solution 2 : with JavaScript

You can also use a JS event

(note the use of `is.null()` as event is not triggered on page 1 initial display):

````
---
title: "Which Page?"
runtime: shiny
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

<script>
$("body").on("shown.bs.tab", "a[data-toggle='tab']", function(e) {
   Shiny.setInputValue("active_tab", $(e.target).parent().index() + 1);
})
</script>

Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=400}
=====================================
```{r}
textInput("text", NULL)

renderUI({
  if(is.null(input$active_tab) || input$active_tab!=3)
    selectInput("select", NULL, LETTERS[1:5])
})
```

Page 1
=====================================

Page 2
=====================================

Page 3
=====================================
````

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you tell me why `renderUI({tab(); tab(1); NULL})` is needed rather than just `renderUI(tab(1))`?

Comment: The first tab() is a read to trigger the instruction when tab changes,  the second is to set the new value,  the last value (return  value) is Null io render no UI.